# Jasmine unit test Spec on debounceTime with tick and flush, execution context not reaching the service file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I have a service file having a function call with rxjs debounce time, when on writing the spec for the same, the execution context is not reaching to the service file from running the test, but on commenting the  `debounceTime(1000)` then the spec works resulting in success expectation, And I can not remove the debounceTime for the spec purpose.

what I have tried : I have tried to add tick, fackAsync, flush combinations, but no clue what is the issue.

Here is the detailed code and screenshot for easy understanding

```
const saveQuestion$ = this.assessmentDetailMiddleware$.pipe(
      filter(filterForQuestionSave),
      debounceTime(1000), //THIS IS CAUSING THE ISSUE, if i remove this, it will work. but it is needed
      rxMap(() => of(checkIfSupposedToTriggerTheSave())),
      switchMap(triggerSave => (!!triggerSave ? this.saveSectionResponses() : NEVER)),
      rxMap((assessmentModel: IAssessmentModel) =>
        assessmentModel
          ? this.assessmentDetailAdapter.convertAssessmentStructure(assessmentModel)
          : false
      ),
      tap(
        (assessmentModel: IAssessmentModel) =>
          assessmentModel && handleSectionUpdatesToStore(assessmentModel)
      ),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log('First this should display'); //THIS IS NOT GETTING DISPLAYED
        this.aaDetailSaveHelperStoreService.saveInProgress(false);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
```

My unit test spec

```
 fit('should call saveInProgress on catchError', fakeAsync(() => {
        mockAaDetailSaveHelperStoreService.getSaveMetada.and.returnValue({
          questionIdsToSave: [1],
          subQuestionIdsToSave: [1],
        });        
        mockAaDetailSaveHelperStoreService.saving.and.returnValue(true);
        const spySaveSectionResponses = spyOn(service, 'saveSectionResponses');
        spySaveSectionResponses.and.returnValues(throwError('error 2'));
        const action = {
          type: 'SAVE_QUESTION',
          payload: () => Promise.resolve,
        };

        service.assessmentDetailMiddleware$.subscribe(data => {
          //  expect(true).toBe(true);
          console.log('now display this : ');
          expect(mockAaDetailSaveHelperStoreService.saveInProgress).toHaveBeenCalled(); //THIS IS NOT DETECTED, SINCE THE EXECUTION NOT REACHED THE SERVICE FILE DUE TO `debounceTime(1000)`.  
          //expect(true).toBe(true);
          flush();
          //
        });
        flush();
        tick(1000);
        service.assessmentDetailMiddleware$.next(action);
        discardPeriodicTasks();
      }));
    })
```

Now the problem is the flow of execution is coming like , first the console inside .spec is displayed WITHOUT displaying the console inside spec, due to this the expectation is not deetcted.

[image: Screenshot]

Now here is the success spec, WITHOUT debounceTime, and it is working

```
const saveQuestion$ = this.assessmentDetailMiddleware$.pipe(
      filter(filterForQuestionSave),
      //debounceTime(1000), //NOW spec WORKS,
      rxMap(() => of(checkIfSupposedToTriggerTheSave())),
      switchMap(triggerSave => (!!triggerSave ? this.saveSectionResponses() : NEVER)),
      rxMap((assessmentModel: IAssessmentModel) =>
        assessmentModel
          ? this.assessmentDetailAdapter.convertAssessmentStructure(assessmentModel)
          : false
      ),
      tap(
        (assessmentModel: IAssessmentModel) =>
          assessmentModel && handleSectionUpdatesToStore(assessmentModel)
      ),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log('First this should display');
        this.aaDetailSaveHelperStoreService.saveInProgress(false);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
```

Please Let me know if need more info

[image: Success]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to write the tick inside the subscribe() block in spec

```
service.assessmentDetailMiddleware$.subscribe(() => {
          tick(1500); //Commented in the below lines and added here.

         expect(mockAaDetailAdapterService.convertAssessmentStructure).toHaveBeenCalled();
          discardPeriodicTasks();
        });
...
//tick(1500);
```